# Does installing Windows and Linux slow down computer?

Tags: windows-7, linux, windows-8

I have Windows 8.1 already installed in my laptop. Now i'm thinking o installing Linux too. Is it a good idea? will it slow down my system?

Comment: It would be useful to understand what you are trying to do here. If you are merely talking about dual-booting Windows/Linux then no, it will not slow down your machine. We are simply talking about filling space on a hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you have the OS installed.

If you create a partition for Linux and install it as a dual boot configuration, then the answer is no, the performance  will be the same. Windows will not know anything about Linux, but Linux will be able to access the Windows partition.

If you install Linux to run in a virtual machine inside Windows, then Windows will perform identically, but Linus would run a little slower (not that you would notice it). You would need to benchmark it to see any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it will have a slight negative effect if you don't make a partition common to both Linux and Windows for file exchange.

When you click 'Shut Down', Windows 8 doesn't shut down completely. It hibernates all the system processes and reloads them as they were at the time of Shut Down. This gives us blazingly fast boot times. But it causes a few problems, too.

If you need to access a file saved on the Windows partition, then you'll either have to mount the position as read only in Linux or remove the hiberfile.sys. Removing the hiberfile means that next time Windows would need to boot the old way, excruciatingly slowly.
Alternatively, you could 'Restart' instead of shutting down Windows and starting Linux instead of Windows when it starts. In case of restart, Windows does this the old way.

These problems can be eliminated by using a shared partition or installing Linux in a virtual machine, however, running a virtual machine requires good amount of system resources.